# Papersizes in leaflet class

Tags: paper-size, leaflet

I'm a user over at overleaf.com and would like to print an 11x17" leaflet using the `leaflet` package.

The only papersize option in leaflet that gets me close is `a3paper`, but the results aren't acceptable when printed on 11x17, the only large paper I have to work with.

I tried `ansibpaper`, but that option returns what appears to be leaflet's default paper size, `a4paper`.

Any pointers?

Comment: Add this code to similar lines of DeclareOption code in the leaflet.cls file: `\DeclareOption{ledgerpaper}{\def\LL@setPaperSize{%
  \paperwidth=17in\paperheight=11in\relax}}%`

Comment: @​wackadoo: you can post your comment as a self-answer to the question if you want, and (a day later I think) click the accept button to mark your own answer as accepted. If you do that it would be good to add a bit of context, i.e., also post some of the 'similar lines' and make a small minimal document where you use the new class option.